# Opening Word Document Link in Word without .doc extension (redirect)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, ms-word, content-management-system

I'm wondering if this is possible without resorting to some convoluted workaround. I have links that reference document management system locations (without a .doc extension). These links, since they lack the extension, open in Internet Explorer, which in turn opens a download dialog. This causes Word not to handle the opening of the document, which causes some minor end-user problems (extended launch time, etc).

Is there any way to automatically redirect the link to Microsoft Word? I found a workaround where links are 'marked' and then opened by JavaScript into Word using Active X - but this is not ideal. As far as I know there is no way to identify a "type" so that the link opens as if it has the .doc extensions (ie: `<a href="***" type=".doc">~</a>`). Ideally I would just want a more "native" way to open the links in Word rather than in IE.

Comment: You ideally want to be storing the MIME types when you originally upload the files. Then when you download you tell the response what the MIME type should be, then the browser can choose the appropriate action

Comment: So, the doc management system knows that it is a Word Doc, but does not prompt the link to be opened by Microsoft Word. Since there is no extension, the browser still initially opens the link in IE.

Comment: Not sure why there is a downvote?

Comment: Are you in control of the server side code? Is this a coding question, or a question about how to use a specific application/system?

Comment: This is a coding question because I have no control over the systems being used or making any changes to that side of things. All I have access to is HTML/CSS/JS. I cannot use server side code or make any system changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said you can only use html, css and javascript, but I thought for completeness sake I would include a couple traditional routes like htaccess and php. The last three are javascript solutions, my bet is that number 5 is the one that will most likely work for you. Number 4 will be blocked by pop-up blockers and number 3 doesn't really send any headers...

1) .htaccess (placed in the folder where the files are stored)

```
<Files *.*>
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
```

2) with php you would set headers for each file

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=msword_doc");
header("Content-type: application/msword");
readfile("msword_doc")
```

3) iframe

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="" style="display:none"></iframe>
<script>
    var frame = document.getElementById("iframe");
    window.onload = setTimeout(function(){
        frame.src="/directory/msword_doc";
    },100);
</script>
```

4) window.open

```
<script>
    window.open("/documents/msword_doc");
</script>
```

5) xmlhttprequest

```
<script>
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open('GET', '/documents/msword_doc');
    client.setRequestHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment');
    client.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/msword');
    client.send();
</script>
```

On a sidenote: NOT ALL word documents use the same mime-type - so your mileage will probably vary.

Comment: Solution 1 worked, in a sense... Changing the MIME type to application/octet-stream in the content system allows the documents to open more fluidly. Not sure why but I think it has something to do with IE8 being utilized causing the doc MIME type to open irregularly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll either have to send the proper mime type (application/msword) or at a minimum make the file accessible at the proper extenstion (.doc). If you have no control over the system then you're SOL.

Have you actually tried with the .doc extension? I imagine you have, but some systems are set up to handle several, even arbitrary extensions that basically tell the back end what format is desired. And it will then send that format back with the proper mime types, etc.